# Is it possible to inject a list of resolved objects into a constructor using Autofac?

Tags: c#-4.0, collections, autofac, code-injection

I'm new to Autofac (3) and am using it to find a number of classes in several assemblies that implement IRecognizer.

So I have:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).As<IRecognizer>();
```

which is fine.

But I'd like to inject references to the found components into a constructor - sort of:

```
public Detector(List<IRecognizer> recognizers)
{
    this.Recognizers = recognizers;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Autofac supports the `IEnumerable<T>` as a [relationship type:](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html)

> For example, when Autofac is injecting a constructor parameter of type
>   `IEnumerable<ITask>` it will not look for a component that supplies
>   `IEnumerable<ITask>`. Instead, the container will find all
>   implementations of `ITask` and inject all of them.

So change your constructor to:

```
public Detector(IEnumerable<IRecognizer> recognizers)
{
    this.Recognizers = new List<IRecognizer>(recognizers);
}
```

Comment: nemesv I have a very similar question - don't suppose you could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363768/include-list-of-resolved-dependancies-of-irepository-with-autofac