# Get list of all implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, interface

I've got 3 classes with the same interface:

```
cppTopicGenerator : TopicGenerator
phpTopicGenerator : TopicGenerator
javaTopicGenerator : TopicGenerator
```

And I created a facade for them where I try to use them as below:

```
public class MyFacade 
{
    private readonly List<TopicGenerator> generators;

    public void BusinessLogic(string extension)
    {
            MyParser(extenstion).generate();
    }


    private TopicGenerator MyParser(string extension)
    {
        foreach (var generator in generators)
        {
            if (generator.Accept(extension))
            {
                return generator;
            }
        }
        throw new NotFoundException($"Generator for {extension} doesnt exist.");
    }
}
```

the question is, how should've created this Generator list? I need to create manually the list of all generators like:

```
private readonly List<TopicGenerator> generators = new List(
        {
            new CppTopicGenerator()
            new PhpTopicGenerator()
            new JavaTopicGenerator()
        });
```

Or is it possible to inject them somehow automatically?

Comment: How are you going to use them? How do you know in your code if you need a `CppTopicGenerator` or `PhpTopicGenerator`?

Comment: Topic generator interface has 2 methods, 1 of them is generate() which is my business logic, and second one is Accept(string extension)

I'll use that Generator, which will return true when Accept is invoked.

Comment: Some service container implementations allow you to add multiple registrations for the same interface, and then take a dependency on `IEnumerable<ISomeInterface>` to get a collection with all the concrete implementations. Since you're not saying which container library you're using, it's impossible to say whether this is possible using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely yes, you can inject it via IoC containers. But, it depends on your needs. If your `Generator` too complicated and need lots of references you can use IoC(e.x. [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac)), but if it lightweight I prefer to create it manually.

Examples(All examples in console application):
1) Manually

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var service = new MyFacade();

            service.MyParser("foo");
            service.MyParser("bar");
            service.MyParser("foobar");
        }
    }

    public class MyFacade
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IGenerator> _generators;

        public MyFacade()
        {
            _generators = new List<IGenerator>()
            {
                new CppTopicGenerator(),
                new PhpTopicGenerator(),
                new JavaTopicGenerator(),
            };
        }

        public IGenerator MyParser(string extension)
        {
            foreach (var generator in _generators)
            {
                if (generator.Accept(extension))
                {
                    return generator;
                }
            }

            throw new NotFoundException($"Generator for {extension} doesnt exist.");
        }
    }

    public interface IGenerator
    {
        bool Accept(string extension);
    }

    public class CppTopicGenerator : IGenerator
    {
        public bool Accept(string extension)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CppTopicGenerator checking executed");
            return extension == "foo";
        }
    }

    public class PhpTopicGenerator : IGenerator
    {
        public bool Accept(string extension)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PhpTopicGenerator checking executed");
            return extension == "bar";
        }
    }

    public class JavaTopicGenerator : IGenerator
    {
        public bool Accept(string extension)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("JavaTopicGenerator checking executed");
            return extension == "foobar";
        }
    }
}
```

2) Autofac:

```
class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()).As<IGenerator>();
            builder.RegisterType<MyFacade>();

            var container = builder.Build();

            using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var service = scope.Resolve<MyFacade>();

                service.MyParser("foo");
                service.MyParser("bar");
                service.MyParser("foobar");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyFacade
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IGenerator> _generators;

        public MyFacade(IEnumerable<IGenerator> generators)
        {
            _generators = generators;
        }

        public IGenerator MyParser(string extension)
        {
            foreach (var generator in _generators)
            {
                if (generator.Accept(extension))
                {
                    return generator;
                }
            }

            throw new NotFoundException($"Generator for {extension} doesnt exist.");
        }
    }

    public interface IGenerator
    {
        bool Accept(string extension);
    }

    public class CppTopicGenerator : IGenerator
    {
        public bool Accept(string extension)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CppTopicGenerator checking executed");
            return extension == "foo";
        }
    }

    public class PhpTopicGenerator : IGenerator
    {
        public bool Accept(string extension)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PhpTopicGenerator checking executed");
            return extension == "bar";
        }
    }

    public class JavaTopicGenerator : IGenerator
    {
        public bool Accept(string extension)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("JavaTopicGenerator checking executed");
            return extension == "foobar";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give me example how would've it look like?

Comment: @degath with autofac?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346415/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-list-of-resolved-objects-into-a-constructor-using-aut
This is what you need

Comment: Thanks, give me some time to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reflect them from the Assembly and then Instantiate them via Activator:

```
    public MyFacade() {
        //Reflect them
        var type = typeof(TopicGenerator);
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface);
        //Instantiate them
        generators = types.Select(t => Activator.CreateInstance(t) as TopicGenerator).ToList();
    }
```

this way you'll find all classes that implement TopicGenerator and you wont need to add them manually if you create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to achieve this.

```
private static readonly List<TopicGenerator> generators = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(TopicGenerator)))
        .Select(x => (TopicGenerator)Activator.CreateInstance(x))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: If `TopicGenerator` is really an interface (not a class), then `x.BaseType == …` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the list using following.

```
var list = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                    .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                    .Where(p => typeof(TopicGenerator).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass && !p.IsAbstract)
                    .Select(x => (TopicGenerator)Activator.CreateInstance(x)).ToList<TopicGenerator>();
```

What it does is, it reflects and iterates over the types in assembly and check if particular interface is implemented. The `!p.IsAbstract` would ensure abstract classes are not listed.