# Get resolved dependancies of IRepository with AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, dependency-injection, autofac

With interfaces set up like so:

```
public interface IRepository { };

public interface IFirstRepository : IRepository { };
public interface ISecondRepository : IRepository { };
public interface IThirdRepository : IRepository { };
```

And a Controller that needs some but not all of these repositories:

```
public class TestController : BaseController 
{
    private IFirstRepository mFirstRepository;
    private ISecondRepository mSecondRepository;
    // Standard DI for MVC 
    public TestController(IFirstRepository first, ISecondRepository second)
    {
        mFirstRepository = first;
        mSecondRepository = second;
    }
}
```

And `BaseController` looks like:

```
public class BaseController : Controller {
     public IEnumerable<IRepository> GetRepos()
     {
         // One solution is to use reflection 
         // to get all properties that are IRepositories.
         // Something along the lines of;
         return typeof(this).GetProperties().Where(prop=>prop is IRepository);

         // But is there a way to use the AutoFac context
         // to get the repos, rather than use reflection?
         // it surely already has that info since it
         // was able to call the constructor correctly?
     }
}
```

**Is there a way `BaseController` can utilize the AutoFac context and existing info to get the collection of the `IRepository` instances requested by the `TestController`?**

Autofac surely already has that info since it was able to call the constructor with the correct instances.

NB: The only reason I don't just use reflection here is performance concerns.

Comment: I don't think if this is possible and I think this is bad design IMHO, but you can create one class that inject set of your repositories and holds them and then inject your one class in controller

Comment: Hey @daremachine, this is working with an existing codebase with 50-70 existing controllers. The goal here is not to have to define a list for each existing controller individually.

Answer (score 1):

There's not an easy way to do this out of the box. If you find yourself in this situation, generally it means you have an interface design problem. [There's an FAQ walking through an example of why this is, as well as some options.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

If you really, really need to do this, then I'd probably look at adding [metadata to each of the registrations](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) where you have a metadata entry for each controller requiring that particular repository, then filter at the constructor using the [metadata filter attribute](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#metadatafilterattribute). Again, [the FAQ I mentioned](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) walks through this and shows examples.

But if it was *me* working in this system... I'd step back and look at my interface design to see how to get away from needing this sort of filter in the first place. If they all can't be treated equally (Liskov substitution principle) then it indicates there are different interfaces required.

Comment: Heya Travis, thanks for the answer. I think maybe the constructor as part of the solution might be misconstruing what I'm trying to achieve here. I've updated the question quite substantially if you wouldn't mind taking another look?

Comment: The updated question doesn't make any sense. Autofac will inject things into the constructor. It's not about aggregating property types. So I guess the answer is "no, Autofac doesn't do that." I'd still really, really, really question WHY that needs to happen and change the design so it's not required.

Comment: Yeah no worries. I just figured that internally it wouldve had to do the work anyway to know what concrete types were passed into which Constructors. Regarding re-design, this project is far past the point where it would be feasible. Sounds like I'm barking up the wrong tree here so will close the question and use reflection. Thanks again for your help.